# mysql errors when using mysql console

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, access-denied

I am using wamp and i am trying to access to phpMyAdmin in order to dealing with database I get the error 1045
[image]

And when I try to solve it by using mysql console and typing "user mysql;" command I get the message error 1044 [image]

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: run mysql -u root -p in bash, not at the MySQL command-line. If you are in mysql, you can exit by typing exit.

Comment: Which password do you entered ?

Comment: please edit this question so that it contains code snippets in text rather than images. The reason is to make it searchable by others later.

Comment: This is not imgur - post code, errors, text, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to select a database is `use` and not `user`

```
use <database-name>;
```

So for example

```
use mysql;
```

Comment: thanks ...you are right but i tryed all methodes but i get the 1045 error again...i am so disappointed

Answer (score 0):

The error you get in phpMyAdmin is because you are not entering the correct password for the root@localhost account.

The error you get in the console is because you are logged in with the anonymous (blank) user (the message mentions ''@localhost). So type `mysql -u root -p`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: phpmyadmin-1045mysql-error]

For the above error, please follow below steps:

**Step 1:**

- Open command line
- `use database-name`
- `UPDATE database-name.user SET Password=PASSWORD("EnterYourPasswordHere") WHERE User="root";`
- Press Enter
- Flush the privileges by typing: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
- Type `Exit` and enter

**Step 2:**

After this open `config.inc.php` file present inside your wamp folder. In my case it is present at `D-Drive > WAMP > APPS > phpmyadmin > config.inc.php`

- Find the following line of code: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`
- Replace the empty string with the newly set password that you created in step 1.
- Click Save and close the file.

Now you should be able to access your database through phpmyadmin.